# Interactive Image/User Interface and Drawing

Tags: android

I want a static image with touch-activated regions that call certain functions to redraw shapes on the screen.

For example, I touch a defined region and a square will redraw into a line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ImageView to show the image in Android.

Then provide onTouch Listener for the image view and when the touch happens, store the pointer location to a global variable and return false.

Then when the onclick event happens for the ImageView, you can get the pointer location from global variables and based on the location, you can act accordingly.